# How do I list multiple results in a single row?

Tags: mysql

I would like to query my tables to produce this output.

[image]

Here is the initial data:

```
CREATE TABLE Order_Tester (
    OrderID int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
    TesterID int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID,TesterID),
    KEY OrderID (OrderID),
    KEY TesterID (TesterID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
INSERT INTO Order_Tester VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO Order_Tester VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO Order_Tester VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO Order_Tester VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO Order_Tester VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO Order_Tester VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO Order_Tester VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO Order_Tester VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO Order_Tester VALUES (4, 4);
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    ID int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    Name varchar(50) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (1, 'Order 1');
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (2, 'Order 2');
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (3, 'Order 3');
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (4, 'Order 4');
CREATE TABLE Organizations (
    ID int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
    Name varchar(50) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
INSERT INTO Organizations VALUES (1, 'Auto-dealer.ru');
INSERT INTO Organizations VALUES (2, 'autoRATING.ru');
INSERT INTO Organizations VALUES (3, 'autoPotrebitel.ru');
CREATE TABLE Testers (
    ID int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    FirstName varchar(50) default NULL,
    LastName varchar(50) default NULL,
    OrganizationID int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    KEY OrganizationID (OrganizationID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
INSERT INTO Testers VALUES (1, 'A', 'AA', 1);
INSERT INTO Testers VALUES (2, 'B', 'BB', 1);
INSERT INTO Testers VALUES (3, 'C', 'CC', 2);
INSERT INTO Testers VALUES (4, 'D', 'DD', 3);
ALTER TABLE `Order_Tester`
ADD CONSTRAINT order_tester_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (TesterID) REFERENCES testers (ID),
ADD CONSTRAINT order_tester_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES orders (ID);
```

This is a list of sample orders attached to them with testers. Moreover, the testers are listed separated by commas, and in brackets the organization to which they belong. If column TestersName obtained several testers that belong to the same organization, the name is not duplicated, but indicated only once at the end.

I tried...

```
SELECT CONCAT(orders.name) AS OrderName,
       CONCAT( FirstName ,'', LastName ) AS TesterName
FROM orders, testers,order_tester
WHERE orders.ID = OrderID
  AND testers.ID = TesterID
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've done some editing to better format your question. What queries have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: query that return all data from all tables and have look like this: http://s008.radikal.ru/i303/1509/49/375152ca6e91.png

Comment: I tried something like this: 
SELECT CONCAT(orders.name) AS OrderName ,
 CONCAT( FirstName ,'', LastName ) AS TesterName 
FROM orders,testers,order_tester
 WHERE orders.ID = OrderID  AND testers.ID = TesterID ;

Comment: But, I dunno how to achieve looks that I need: http://s008.radikal.ru/i303/1509/49/375152ca6e91.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To group multiple rows together, use a `GROUP BY` clause with [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to display all the grouped rows in one cell.

```
SELECT CONCAT(orders.name) AS OrderName ,
       GROUP_CONCAT(
         CONCAT( FirstName ,'', LastName, ' ', '(', Organizations.Name, ')' )
       ) AS TesterNames
FROM orders
JOIN order_tester  ON orders.ID = OrderID
JOIN testers       ON testers.ID = TesterID
JOIN organizations ON organizations.ID = OrganizationID
GROUP BY OrderName
```

[Try it out yourself](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef8ec5/7).